# LINQ - Proj does not exist in the current

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following code:

```
    if (pick == null || pick == "active")
    {
       var Proj = db.usp_Train(idnbr)
                 .Where(a => a.Inactive == false).ToList();
     }        
     else 
     {
       var Proj = db.usp_Train(idnbr).ToList();

     }

return PartialView(Proj);
```

For where I have *return PartialView(Projs)* I get a message saying that **Proj does not exist in the current** Any idea on how I can fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring `Proj` within the scopes of the `if` and `else` blocks - so it doesn't exist outside those blocks. You want something like:

```
// Or whatever the type is...
List<Train> proj;

if (pick == null || pick == "active")
{
    proj = db.usp_Train(idnbr)
             .Where(a => a.Inactive == false).ToList();
}        
else 
{
    proj = db.usp_Train(idnbr).ToList();
}
return PartialView(proj);
```

Alternatively, you could use the conditional operator:

```
bool pickActive = pick == null || pick == "active";
var proj = pickActive ? db.usp_Train(idnbr).Where(a => !a.Inactive).ToList()
                      : db.usp_Train(idnbr).ToList();
return PartialView(proj);
```

Or selectively apply the condition, which removes all the redundancy:

```
IQueryable<Train> proj = db.usp_Train(idnbr);
if (pick == null || pick == "active")
{
    proj = proj.Where(a => !a.Inactive);
}
return PartialView(proj.ToList());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (pick == null || pick == "active")
{
    return PartialView(db.usp_Train(idnbr).Where(a => a.Inactive == false).ToList());
}
return PartialView(db.usp_Trainin(idnbr).ToList());
```

or if you prefer:

```
List<Project> projects;
if (pick == null || pick == "active")
{
    projects = db.usp_Train(idnbr).Where(a => a.Inactive == false).ToList();
}
else
{
    projects = db.usp_Trainin(idnbr).ToList();
}
return PartialView(projects);
```

Comment: I wouldn't set the variable to `null` in the first line of the second version - that suggests the value is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `Proj` in too narrow of a scope.

```
//define Proj here!
List<Train> Proj = null;

if (pick == null || pick == "active")
    {
       Proj = db.usp_Train(idnbr)
                 .Where(a => a.Inactive == false).ToList();
     }        
     else 
     {
       Proj = db.usp_Train(idnbr).ToList();

     }

return PartialView(Proj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your `Proj` variable remains in scope wherever it is accessed. Since `var` variables need to be assigned where they’re declared, my suggestion would be to refactor your logic to avoid the repeated declaration:

```
var proj = db.usp_Train(idnbr);

if (pick == null || pick == "active")
    proj = proj.Where(a => a.Inactive == false);

return PartialView(proj.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Proj is limited in scope. Declare it like this:

```
    (whatever type Proj is) Proj;

    if (pick == null || pick == "active") 
        { 
            Proj = db.usp_Train(idnbr) 
                     .Where(a => a.Inactive == false).ToList(); 
         }         
         else  
         { 
            Proj = db.usp_Trainin(idnbr).ToList(); 

         } 


return PartialView(Proj);
```